# SQL select all records from one table which appear < 3 times in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got two tables:

```
Event
+----------+---------+--------------+
| event_id | name    | date         |
+----------+------+-----------------+
| 1        | Event 1 | 26/03/2012   |
+----------+------+-----------------+
| 2        | Event 2 | 27/03/2012   |
+----------+------+-----------------+

Reservation
+----------------+------------+--------------+
| reservation_id | date       | themed_id    |
+----------------+------------+--------------+
| 1              | 26/03/2012 | 1            |
+----------------+------------+--------------+
| 2              | 26/03/2012 | 1            |
+----------------+------------+--------------+
| 3              | 27/03/2012 | 2            |
+----------------+------------+--------------+
| 4              | 26/03/2012 | 1            |
+----------------+------------+--------------+
```

How will I display all the events which appear less than 3 times in the reservation table.

The output will be:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
| event_id | name    | date         |
+----------+------+-----------------+
| 2        | Event 2 | 27/03/2012   |
+----------+------+-----------------+
```

As event two has only appeared once in reservation

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself first? We're here to assist you, not give you a complete written solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Event
WHERE event_id IN (
SELECT themed_id
FROM Reservation
GROUP BY themed_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)
```

I have not tested but the base idea is this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `Event.event_id` = `Reservation.themed_id`? If so:

**Edit:** Changed to a LEFT JOIN to include events with 0 reservations.

```
SELECT
    Event.event_id,
    Event.name,
    Event.date
FROM
    Event
LEFT JOIN Reservation ON Event.event_id = Reservation.themed_id
GROUP BY
    Event.event_id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT Reservation.reservation_id) < 3
```